# Refresh part of JSP containing dojo tabbed panel in a DIV

Tags: jquery, struts2, dojo

I have a jsp containing tabbed panel using dojo.
This is the JSP -

```
<div id="protoDevTDPRevLogTab">
    <sx:tabbedpanel id="tabContainer" selectedTab="2" >
        <sx:div label="Prototype Development (Virtual/Physical)" id = "protoDevTabId" disabled="true" >
            Prototype Development (Virtual/Physical)                
        </sx:div>
        <sx:div label="Set Maker Layout"  theme="ajax" preload="true" href="%{protoDevTDPRevLogDTO.url}" id = "protoDevTDPRevLogDTO.setMLTabId" disabled="true"/>

        <sx:div label="Set Maker Layout"  theme="ajax" preload="true" href="%{protoDevTDPRevLogDTO.url}" id = "protoDevTDPRevLogDTO.setMLTabId" disabled="%{protoDevTDPRevLogDTO.disabled}" />

        <sx:div label="Shipping / Line Trial" id = "protoDevTDPRevLogDTO.shippingLTTabId" >
            <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="shippingLineTrial">
                <tr class="tab_inputrow"/>
                <tr class="tab_inputrow">
                    <td width="30%">
                    <input type="button" value="Go For TDP Creation" id="goForTDPCreationbtnId" class="btn_enabled" 
                        onclick="sendNotificationToPackSuplier();" style="width: 120px" align="left"></input>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="tab_inputrow"/>
            </table>
        </sx:div>

    </sx:tabbedpanel>
</div>
```

In one of the table on button click I have to do some business logic which will change the data in other tabs.

So i want to refresh the entire tabbed panel section.

I have tried using jQuery ajax like this -

```
    $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "updateMLSupplier.action?packSupplierNumber="+packSupplierNumber+"&packSupplierName="+packSupplierName+"&rcmid="+rcmid,
          data: "data",
          success: function (response) {
            var url = "tabbedProtoDevTDPRevLog.action?&packSupplierName="+encodeURIComponent(packSupplierName)+"&rcmid="+encodeURIComponent(rcmid);

// This url has the code to refresh the data contained in tabbed panel.
//Also the success of this ajax is the tabbed jsp.
            $("#protoDevTDPRevLogTab").load(url);
        },
          dataType: "text"
    });
```

Here is the struts mapping -

```
<action name="tabbedProtoDevTDPRevLog" class="protoDevTDPRevLogAction" method="loadProtoDevTDPRevLog">
        <result name="success">tabbedPanel.jsp
        </result>
</action>
```

The problem is - tabbedPanel.jsp has code like : `<sx:tabbedpanel id="tabContainer" selectedTab="%{protoDevTDPRevLogDTO.tabToDisplay}" >`,   so in the jQuery ajax load method the Dojo prefix are replaced with some dojo javascript. The end result the JSP is not replaced in the specified DIV.

Is there any alternate solution to this problem. My only concern is to refresh the dojo tabbed panel contents.

Comment: Dojo plugin is deprecated since years. If you are already using jQuery, why not using struts2-jQuery-plugin, or raw jQuery, dropping dojo-tags at all ?

Comment: I have tried that. To use struts-jquery I will have to update the current jars. That might break some existing functionality. Also jquery tabs look and feel is different

Comment: Look and feel can be easily tuned with CSS. +1 because you've tried :)

Comment: I know how to achieve the result using jquery tabs and for look and feel write some new css. But is the same possible with dojo ajax ?

Comment: If you are trying to refresh data in one of the tabs then why are you reloading whole div with the tabs? Instead refresh only part inside required tab.

Comment: When i submit on one tab based on condition other tab will open with new data. This is how the functionality goes.

Comment: So update just required div, not the whole `tabbedpanel`.

Comment: @AleksandrM , that's the main issue. If you look at my ajax call, the response is a jsp page on the success callback. But the jsp is not rendered properly, since it contains dojo tags, it is internally being converted to javascript elements with struts dojo plugin

Comment: Do you want `tabbedpanel` inside another `tabbedpanel`'s tab?

Comment: @AleksandrM I am replacing the existing tabbed panel jsp with the tabbed panel jsp returned as a success on my action hit, refer to code above.

Comment: Don't do that. Instead replace data in some tab.

Comment: @AleksandrM the problem is some of the tabs will be hidden, and I am facing difficulties hiding and re-showing them based on conditions alone using javascript. So I thought writing the conditional logic inside jsp using conditional if and i can set the data in the pojo at my Action

Comment: Well you should include this info into your question. Also show your `tabbedPanel.jsp`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved the solution using jQuery tabs and including the dynamic content with dojo as below -

```
<div id="protoDevTDPRevLogTab">
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Prototype Development (Virtual/Physical)</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Set Maker Layout</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Shipping / Line Trial</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tabs-4">TDP Verification</a></li>
                  </ul>
                  <div id="tabs-1">
                    <p>Prototype Development (Virtual/Physical)</p>
                  </div>
                  <div id="tabs-2">
                    <sx:div label="Set Maker Layout"  theme="ajax" preload="true" href="%{protoDevTDPRevLogDTO.url}" id = "protoDevTDPRevLogDTO.setMLTabId" disabled="true"/>
                  </div>
                  <div id="tabs-3">
                    <sx:div label="Shipping / Line Trial" id = "protoDevTDPRevLogDTO.shippingLTTabId" >
                            <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="shippingLineTrial">
                                <tr class="tab_inputrow"/>
                                <tr class="tab_inputrow">
                                    <td width="30%">
                                    <input type="button" value="Go For TDP Creation" id="goForTDPCreationbtnId" class="btn_enabled" 
                                        onclick="sendNotificationToPackSuplier();" style="width: 120px" align="left"></input>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="tab_inputrow"/>
                            </table>
                        </sx:div>
                  </div>
                  <div id="tabs-4">
                        <sx:div label="TDP Verification" theme="ajax" preload="true" href="tdpVerfication" id = "protoDevTDPRevLogDTO.tdpVerificationTabId" disabled="%{protoDevTDPRevLogDTO.disabled}" />
                  </div>
</div>
```

javascript code -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $("#protoDevTDPRevLogTab").tabs({selected:1,disabled: [0]});

//this will change conditionally.
            $('[href="#tabs-2"]').closest('li').hide();
            $('[href="#tabs-3"]').closest('li').hide();
    } );
```

Server side code remains the same